# Is it ok to use Gherkin syntax to describe scenarios for backend applications?

Tags: test-design, testcase, documentation, test-creation, validation

I use gherkin syntax to write the scenarios of features that involve user interaction. However, I'm not sure if it is the correct syntax to describe scenarios to test backend applications.

If your answer is yes, could you give me an example of how you would do it?

If your answer is no, could you recommend an alternative?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much my answer will be useful for you; but Yes, we do use the same for testing parts of our applications that work in back-end e.g. we use it for testing webservices response, Database testing and currently we are using it for ETL testing too.

**For example:**

> **Given:** CSV file to be imported is located at xyz location
>
> **When:** ETL process A is executed
>
> **Then:** CSV file Data should be loaded to Warehouse table A

**Another:**

> **Given:** User 'A' is created in system  XYZ
>
> **When:** Sync button is clicked
>
> **Then:** Webservice call containing user information in XML format should be sent to system ABC and a new row should be inserted to its
>   user table